# QEMU: How to convert -net flags into -device & -netdev

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu, macos, packer

I'm trying to emulate Raspberry Pi via QEMU and the following works for me:

```bsh
qemu-system-arm \
    -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
    -boot c \
    -cpu arm1176 \
    -drive "file=2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-lite.img,if=scsi,cache=none,discard=ignore,format=raw" \
    -kernel ./kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie \
    -m 256M \
    -machine type=versatilepb,accel=tcg \
    -name packer-qemu \
    -no-reboot \
    -vnc 127.0.0.1:4 \
    -net nic \
    -net user,id=user.0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

and I'm able to both VNC in via `5904` and SSH in via `5555` (after starting SSHd via VNC). In other words network seems to be set up correctly.

As I discovered [`-net` option has been deprecated](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#The_legacy_-net_option) in favour of `-device` & `-netdev`, so I'd like to translate the above two last flags into "new QEMU".

It appears that the new `-device` flag forces me to pick a driver, which isn't the case with `-net`. I like explicitness, but how do I know what is the default/implicit driver?

Port forwarding in the following example doesn't seem to work anymore (I can't SSH in; connection times out):

```bsh
qemu-system-arm \
    -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
    -boot c \
    -cpu arm1176 \
    -drive "file=2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-lite.img,if=scsi,cache=none,discard=ignore,format=raw" \
    -kernel ./kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie \
    -m 256M \
    -machine type=versatilepb,accel=tcg \
    -name packer-qemu \
    -no-reboot \
    -vnc 127.0.0.1:4 \
    -device e1000,netdev=user.0 \
    -netdev user,id=user.0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

Am I just using wrong driver?

---

QEMU `3.1.0` (installed from Homebrew)

(Host) MacOS `10.14.4`

Comment: I managed to make it work with `-nic user,id=user.0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22` (which seems to be a new flag too) but I'm still very confused about differences between all these flags and I'm still curious whether they are replaceable with each other.

Comment: https://www.qemu.org/2018/05/31/nic-parameter/ provides some background with some hints that these flags may not actually be equivalent. Should I turn this into an answer?

Comment: you should, if it works for you. as a completion, you can check the default network device with `info network` in the qemu monitor (for your machine (versatilepb) it's probably smc91c111.